# How create json format with group-concat mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

How create json format with group-concat mysql?

(I use MySQL)

Example1:

table1:

```
email            |    name  |   phone
-------------------------------------
my1@gmail.com    | Ben      | 6555333
my2@gmail.com    | Tom      | 2322452
my2@gmail.com    | Dan      | 8768768
my1@gmail.com    | Joi      | 3434356
```

like syntax code that not give me the format:

```sql
select email, group-concat(name,phone) as list from table1 
group by email
```

output that I need:

```
email         |    list
------------------------------------------------
my1@gmail.com |  {name:"Ben",phone:"6555333"},{name:"Joi",phone:"3434356"}
my2@gmail.com |  {name:"Tom",phone:"2322452"},{name:"Dan",phone:"8768768"}
```

Comment: If your database is going to grow, this is a bad idea. Better do it using code in your application.

Comment: db static for readonly parpose

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  email,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{name:"', name, '", phone:"',phone,'"}')) list
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
  email;
```

JSON format result -

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| email         | list                                                        |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| my1@gmail.com | {name:"Ben", phone:"6555333"},{name:"Joi", phone:"3434356"} |
| my2@gmail.com | {name:"Tom", phone:"2322452"},{name:"Dan", phone:"8768768"} |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what would happen if name contains a double quote?

Comment: It depends on ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode, if it is activated - then you should double " in names, othervise - it will work.

Comment: hmm this seems to surround the entire "list" json value with double quotes - meaning if you json_encode the entire result the field list will not be encoded and remains a string...

Comment: sorry to say this is not a valid JSON... a JSON array is enclosed between [ and ]

Comment: As a sidenote to my edit, you could use the new JSON functions in MySQL 5.7 if that is an option for you. See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object

Comment: @AntonioOrtells, to make it valid you would, and I did, just adjust the part with `CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(…), ']') list`, this wraps it in array brackets and the comma from GROUP_CONCAT does the rest.

Comment: Just concatenating variable string content into a JSON object is likely to result in errors and open to injection attacks which could have unexpected security implications. I woulc not recommend this solution without properly escaping the variables that go in the JSON string.

Answer (score 117):

With the newer versions of MySQL, you can use JSON_OBJECT function to achieve the desired result, like so:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'name', name,
    'phone', phone
  )
) AS list
```

To get the SQL response ready to be parsed as an array:

```
CONCAT(
  '[',
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'name', name,
      'phone', phone
    )
  ),
  ']'
) AS list
```

This will give you a string like: `[{name: 'ABC', phone: '111'}, {name: 'DEF', phone: '222'}]` which can be JSON parsed.

Comment: Is there a shorthand like `->` or `->>` but for the `CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(...) SEPARATOR ','), ']')` ?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use `IF` to omit the record if its blank? How its written returns `{"name": null, "phone": null}` if its an empty record set.

Comment: for me, the result isn't quite right.. the result is [{\"name\": \"ABC\", \"phone\": \"111\"}, {\"name\": \"DEF\", \"phone\": \"222\"}]    .. its escaping all the double quotes around the field key and values.

Comment: found similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736028/correctly-return-column-as-json-array-in-mysql-after-using-concat-group-concat

Answer (score 41):

## For Mysql 5.7.22+

```sql
    SELECT
        email,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'name', name,
                'phone', phone
            )
        ) AS list
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY email;
```

#### Result:

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| email         | list                                                              |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| my1@gmail.com | [{"name":"Ben", "phone":6555333},{"name":"Joi", "phone":3434356}] |
| my2@gmail.com | [{"name":"Tom", "phone":2322452},{"name":"Dan", "phone":8768768}] |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The only difference is that column `list` is now **Json-valid**, so you can parse directly as **Json**

Comment: The concat() solution trimmed the result, this one not!!

Comment: just a note that json_arrayagg does not define the order it will use.  So at any given time/release, the order you get back may change (eg Ben's object may appear 2nd and Joi first, in the first array returned).  A work around to this is to use group concat with an order by.. until mysql gets the 'order by' working with json_arrayagg

Answer (score 30):

I hope this finds the right eyes.

You can use:

**For arrays** ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)):

```
JSON_ARRAYAGG(col_or_expr) as ...
```

**For objects** ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg)):

```
JSON_OBJECTAGG(key, value) as ...
```

Comment: Important to note that those are available in 5.7.22+ as per  [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html)

Comment: Neither they available in Amazon aurora 5.7 at the time of writing this comment

Answer (score 19):

Devart's answer above is great, but K2xL's question is valid. The answer I found was to hexadecimal-encode the name column using HEX(), which ensures that it will create valid JSON. Then in the application, convert the hexadecimal back into the string.

(Sorry for the self-promotion, but) I wrote a little blog post about this with a little more detail:
http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2015/05/hand-rolling-valid-json-in-mysql-using-group_concat/

[Edit for Oriol] Here's an example:

```
SELECT email,
    CONCAT(
        '[',
        COALESCE(
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT(
                    '{',
                    '\"name\": \"', HEX(name), '\", ',
                    '\"phone\": \"', HEX(phone), '\"',
                    '}')
                ORDER BY name ASC
                SEPARATOR ','),
            ''),
        ']') AS bData
FROM table
GROUP BY email
```

Also note I've added a COALESCE in case there are no items for that email.

Comment: Add the complex concat example in your answer. I think it's very helpful ;-)

Comment: This solved my issue, other solutions failed when decoding the resulting json with invalid chars like tabs, slashes, ...

Comment: the `name` and `phone` keys have to be in `""`(double quotes) to represent a valid json

Comment: kekko12: Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: `TO_BASE64` might lower the overcost that `HEX` introduce (ie: strings are shorter). But use https://stackoverflow.com/a/40235188/2342518 for nowadays MySQLs

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Madacol's answer above, but slightly different. Instead of JSONARRAYAGG, you could also CAST AS JSON:

```
SELECT
        email,
       CAST( CONCAT(
        '[', 
           GROUP_CONCAT(
           JSON_OBJECT(
              'name', name,
              'phone', phone
            )
        ),']') AS JSON )
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY email;
```

**Result:**

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| email         | list                                                              |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| my1@gmail.com | [{"name":"Ben", "phone":6555333},{"name":"Joi", "phone":3434356}] |
| my2@gmail.com | [{"name":"Tom", "phone":2322452},{"name":"Dan", "phone":8768768}] |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what is your DBMS you can use json path in sql server

Comment: sorry i missed that..This is for Mysql 5.7.26

Comment: the only thing to keep in mind like when you use `GROUP_CONCAT` you can have only 1024 characters only. If your JSON has more length then I would suggest the below answer to follow. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58509829/8197832

Answer (score 3):

Going off of @Devart's answer... if the field contains linebreaks or double quotation marks, the result will not be valid JSON.

So, if we know the "phone" field occasionally contains double-quotes and linebreaks, our SQL would look like:

```
SELECT
  email,
  CONCAT(
    '[',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
        '{name:"', 
        name, 
        '", phone:"', 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, '"', '\\\\"'),'\n','\\\\n'), 
        '"}'
      )),
    ']'
  ) AS list
FROM table1 GROUP BY email;
```

If Ben phone has a quote in the middle of it, and Joi's has a newline, the SQL would give (valid JSON) results like:

```
[{name:"Ben", phone:"655\"5333"},{name:"Joi", phone:"343\n4356"}]
```

Comment: Hello, Jonathan could you take a look on my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75136136/replace-with-array-from-a-select-group-concat

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
SELECT email,concat('{name:"',ur_name_column,'",phone:"',ur_phone_column,'"}') as list FROM table1 GROUP BY email;
```

Cheers

Comment: Will throw a warning (and inconsistant results) since you're retrieving a non-grouped non-unique column with a `GROUP BY` clause (and will be prone to JSOn-injection if `ur_name_column` contains double quotes or blackslash)