# How to make array from a single quoted array

Tags: php, arrays

I have no idea How to convert a single quote array into array;

**FOR Example:-**

I have

```
$Array = '["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]';
print_r($Array);
```

Then it is showing like string not an **array**

```
 ["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]
```

so how to convert this into array

like the result will show like this

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 9
    [Value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 25
            [4] => 30
        )

)
```

May be you have why i am putting array in single quote but this is not i am putting.

I Getting an array from DB after `group_concat` in `mysql`

This is the array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GPN] => A
            [PKGID] => PKG01
            [Output] => ["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]
        )
)
```

Here the Output is element coming like it's a string

Comment: yes you right but have a look on the `[Output] => ["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]`

Comment: Maybe the correct solution to this is to look at the query as that is what is creating this issue. _Fix the problem, not the symptom_

Comment: try to put at least a json in the database.

Comment: if you need to use group_concat take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511933/how-create-json-format-with-group-concat-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but it might be dangerous:

```
$Array = '["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]';

eval('$Array = '.$Array.';'); // Could be dangerous

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Array);
echo '</pre>';
```

In my example above, `$Array` is assumed to be data coming from your database such as `[Output] => ["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]`. Since it is coming from the database then that means the possibility exists for the DB data to be malicious and `eval()` will gladly run anything you give it.

Comment: $Array = '["ID" => 9, "Value" => "exec("rm -rf /")"]'; -> just an example of what could happen.

Comment: @M.I. Close, but I think your exact example would just cause a fatal error.

Comment: @M.I. The `group_concat` which OP mentioned would have to output `["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]];exec("rm -rf /")` or just `exec("rm -rf /")` in order for the `eval()` injection to work.

Comment: yes, that is correct, but will still throw an parse exception. eval is not ok to be used like this, he should try to get something else from the database, like a json, found another question on SO :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511933/how-create-json-format-with-group-concat-mysql

Comment: @M.I. I agree but unfortunately OP is not revealing any other details about how their `group_concat` logic is even producing valid syntax for setting an array (assuming PHP >= 5.4); quite frankly, that's impressive. Also, I am sure that something is possible with a join or a PHP loop but without additional details I would be pulling 15 pounds of crap out of a 5 pound bag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` to parse the string as php code like this:

```
$s = '["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]';
eval('$a = ' . $s . ';');
print_r($a);
```

This will work only with php 5.4 and up

**CAUTION**

If this string contains data from user then it is not safe to use `eval`.

**Alternative solution**

If you are the one who populate the database records, i suggests to serialize `Output` values as `json`, using `json_encode`, before insert to database.
Then you can use `json_decode` to access data as array.

Comment: eval can be dangerous but how.

Comment: `eval` executes any given code. So if you don' t know what the code is and what it process, it is not safe to use it like this.

Comment: Thanks @Whiteulver I like your suggestion about about `json_encode`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$str   = '["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]';
$array = eval('return ' . $str . ';');
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'ID' => 9,
  'Value' => 
  array (
    0 => 40,
    1 => 15,
    2 => 20,
    3 => 25,
    4 => 30,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

So, your question is basically how to convert string representation of php array to php array. I don't know any tools for this, however you can use eval function.

`$arr = [];
eval('$arr=' . $Array . ';');
// $arr contains php array`

However this is not recommendable, because you can execute arbitrary code which undermines security of your application. Before using it you should make sure that `$Array` does not contain any malicious code and all strings are escaped.

If you run your application as a root user then it is even more dangerous. For example:
`$Array = 'true?print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']):0'`

The above code will print all the server data of your application.

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution.

```
$array = [
        "ID" => 9,
        "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30],
         ];

print_r($array);
```

Output :

```
 /* Array ( [ID] => 9 [Value] => Array ( [0] => 40 [1] => 15 [2] => 20
 [3]=> 25 [4] => 30 ) ) */
```

for other array :

```
 $array =[

         "0" => [
                "GPN" => A,
                "PKGID" => PKG01,
                "Output" => 
                           [
                            "ID" => 9,
                             "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]
                           ]
                ]
         ];
print_r($array);
```

And output :

```
/*Array ( [0] => Array ( [GPN] => A [PKGID] => PKG01 [Output] => Array ( [ID] => 9 [Value] => Array ( [0] => 40 [1] => 15 [2] => 20 [3] => 25 [4] => 30 ) ) ) ) */
```

advise : the name "PKG01".

> psr-1 :  constants MUST be declared in all upper case

source : [psr-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)

Comment: he has a string to convert it in an array, how does this help?

Comment: He wants to pass an array to an array of arrays

Comment: Not really, he needs to transform a string to array and after that to pass it to another array. He is asking how to make this '["ID" => 9, "Value" => [40,15,20,25,30]]' into an array.